# Accessing an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

This is the snippet of Java code.

```
class Test{  
    public static void main(String[ ] args){
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };       
        int[] b = { 2, 3, 1, 0 };     
        System.out.println( a [ (a = b)[3] ] );  
    }
}
```

Why does it print 1? This is not a homework! I am trying to understand Java. That is related to OCA Java 7 exam.

Comment: Homework?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you just answer your first question?

Comment: I'd just run the code and find out. (Or step in a debugger if you want a close look.)

Comment: Why does this question get so many downvotes? It's not too obvious.

Comment: It also gets you whapped on the head with a rolled up newspaper by your supervisor for using the ridiculous construct in the last line.

Comment: @GolezTrol Because it doesn't look like a legitimate problem, nor is there any evidence of own research (like the result you'd expect, or why you'd expect it) before posting the contrived mess on here. It's also a textbook example of "too localized".

Comment: The point is that any effects of assignment are delayed until after the whole expression is evaluated. That means that the outer `a` doesn't see the inner assignment to `a`.

Comment: Interesting question (even if the syntax is bound to cause issues later).  You should also consider selecting answers for some of your previous questions to keep encouraging community participation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that should be the answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ... to a closed question :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it's not closed yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you refer to `a[ ... ]`, `a` still points to the first array. When the index itself is evaluated, there's an assignment of `b` to `a`. So at that moment, `a` becomes `b`, of which the 3rd item is fetched, which is `0`.

This `0` is used as an index of the array that was already found before. This is the array that `a` pointed to, although `a` itself in the mean time has changed. Therefor it prints the `1`, even though you might expect `2`.

I think that is what this example is trying to show: The array reference is already evaluated and doesn't change once you modify the array variable during the evaluation of the index.

But I wouldn't use this 'feature' in production code. Very unclear.

Comment: Maybe it's for SCJP exam or related.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println( a [ (a = b)[3] ] );
```

First, the value of `a` is evaluated (`{1, 2, 3, 4}`). Next, `a = b` is executed; this assigns the value of `b` to `a` and also *returns* the value of `b`. `b[3] = { 2, 3, 1, 0 }` is `0`, so, ultimately, `{1,2,3,4}[b[3]] = {1,2,3,4}[0] = 1`.

---

To see this, consider the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };            
    System.out.println( a() [ (a = b())[c()] ] );
}

public static int[] a() {
    System.out.println('a');
    return new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}

public static int[] b() {
    System.out.println('b');
    return new int[]{ 2, 3, 1, 0 };
}

public static int c() {
    System.out.println('c');
    return 3;
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
1
```

Comment: According to the tutorial I am referring to first the left part has been executed, i.e. a. And only then goes [(a=b)[3]]

Comment: @uml Indeed, the `a[x]` is executed first, but `x = b[3]`, so `a[b[3]]` is 1.

Comment: This answer is wrong. (a = b) is not executed first. If it would be, the solution would be `2`, not `1`.

Comment: `(a = b)` not only returns `{ 2, 3, 1, 0 }`, but also assigns that array to `a`, in which case `a[0]` would return `2`. Therefor, `a = b` is not what is evaluated first.